# Format dateTime from json string

Tags: datetime

I have some JSON being returned... how can I format these date time strings using c# and JS?

```
{
   "time": 1469257200,
   "summary": "Partly cloudy in the morning.",
   "icon": "partly-cloudy-day",
   "sunriseTime": 1469279237,
   "sunsetTime": 1469330841,
   "moonPhase": 0.63,
    ...... ..... ...
},
```

and help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

was easy once I realized that is a unix timestamp:

```
        public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp)
          {
        // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
        System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
        dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
        return dtDateTime;
          }
```